Not able to compile Lua/LuaTeX scripts with coroutines [coroutine.yield] vs [coroutine.result(name)]
This question deals with Lua coroutines, a functionality I want to access in my Lua/LuaTeX scripts. The following snippets are without or with argument to pass (for this latter, that's what I want as a final goal).
As a total beginner with Lua/LuaTeX scripts, I did a lot of trial/error without success but the original error must be certainly obvious for experts. After reading several posts and documentations, two orientations are at disposal in order to declare coroutines: via named function or not. For these two way of doing, it seems that the issue comes from the coroutine.yield and (and/or) coroutine.results functions.
Then few examples with LuaTeX I saw date from 2010/2011; may be there are some modifications in the meantime. What have I missed in case of changement? Therefore, why my coding is "dirty"? (It's a little bit hard to debug to me for the moment being)
Code testing
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
-- Main function of the coroutine
--function luadisplay (argval)
--  tex.print("..argval..")
function luadisplay ()
  for i = 0, 1, 1 do
    if i==0 then
      tex.print{"OK0"}
      tex.print(coroutine.yield())
    end
    if i==1 then
      tex.print{"OK1"}
      tex.print(coroutine.yield())
    end
  end
end
-- Creating coroutine
luacoroutine = coroutine.create(luadisplay)
-- Starting and obtaining results
--tex.print("coroutine.resume(luacoroutine)") -- Does not work if "coroutine.yield" uncommented
\end{luacode}

\begin{luacode} -- That's compile but can't obtain result
  -- Creating the damned coroutine directly (without argument)
  myco = coroutine.create( function()
    for i = 0, 1, 1 do
      if i==0 then
        tex.print{"OK0"}
        tex.print(coroutine.yield())
      end
      if i==1 then
        tex.print{"OK1"}
        tex.print(coroutine.yield())
      end
      coroutine.resume(myco)
    end
  end)
\end{luacode}

%\directlua{require("luatexse.lua")} % If external file

%\newcommand{\luacoroutinecmd}{\directlua{luacoroutine()}} -- Without argument not works
%\newcommand{\luacoroutinecmd}[1]{\directlua{luacoroutine("#1")}} -- With argument not works

%\newcommand{\mycocmd}{\directlua{myco()}} -- Without argument not works

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Is it work?

\bigskip\bigskip

%\luacoroutinecmd{Hi!}

\end{document}


it's a bit hard to know what to test in your example as so much is commented out. How to know what to uncomment and what you expect in that case? It would be easier if you edited it to be one specific example even if it gives an error and say what output you expected. Also by "The few examples with LuaTeX I saw date from 2010/2011;" do you mean you found examples that claimed to work then and don't now? can you give a link?

In 2010, LuaTeX would have been using Lua 5.1, but it's been using Lua 5.3 since 2019, so that's likely the source of the discrepancy.

The error message apparently means you are calling the coroutine as a function. Calling it via coroutine.resume runs without error but I'm not sure what result is intended.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
-- Main function of the coroutine
--function luadisplay (argval)
--  tex.print("..argval..")
function luadisplay (m)
  for i = 0, 1, 1 do
    if i==0 then
      tex.print{"OK0[" .. m .. "]"}
      tex.print(coroutine.yield())
    end
    if i==1 then
      tex.print{"OK1[" .. m .. "]"}
      tex.print(coroutine.yield())
    end
  end
end
-- Creating coroutine
luacoroutine = coroutine.create(luadisplay)
-- Starting and obtaining results
--tex.print("coroutine.resume(luacoroutine)") -- Does not work if "coroutine.yield" uncommented
\end{luacode}


\newcommand{\luacoroutinecmd}[1]{\directlua{coroutine.resume(luacoroutine,"#1")}} %-- With argument not works


\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Is it work?

\bigskip\bigskip

A \luacoroutinecmd{Hi!}

\bigskip\bigskip

B \luacoroutinecmd{Hi!}

\bigskip\bigskip

C \luacoroutinecmd{Hi!}

\end{document}


Many thanks. I am sorry for the lack of reactivity. I agree with you, my question is not clear enough. It was a little confused. Nevertheless, your answer is perfect and suits for my needs. I'll dig more in deep with my real use case. Thanks again.
